# Python: data to file then data from text file to list - TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, string, byte, pickle

I'm a beginner in programming and have decided to teach myself Python. After a few days, i've decided to code a little piece. I's pretty simple:

- date of today
- page i am at (i'm reading a book)
- how i feel
- then i add the data in a file. every time i launch the program, it adds a new line of data in the file
- then i extract the data to make a list of lists.

truth is, i wanted to re-write my program in order to pickle a list and then unpickle the file. However, as i'm coping with an error i can't handle, i really really want to understand how to solve this. Therefore i hope you will be able to help me out :)

I've been struggling for the past hours on this apparently a simple and stupid problem. Though i don't find the solution. Here is the error and the code:

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dailyshot.py", line 25, in <module>
    SaveData(todaysline)
  File "dailyshot.py", line 11, in SaveData
    mon_pickler.dump(datatosave)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

CODE:

```
import pickle
import datetime

def SaveData(datatosave):
    with open('journey.txt', 'wb') as thefile:
        my_pickler = pickle.Pickler(thefile)
        my_pickler.dump(datatosave)
        thefile.close()

todaylist = []
today = datetime.date.today()
todaylist.append(today)

page = input('Page Number?\n')
feel = input('How do you feel?\n')

todaysline = today.strftime('%d, %b %Y') + "; " + page + "; " + feel + "\n"

print('Thanks and Good Bye!')

SaveData(todaysline)

print('let\'s make a list now...')

thefile = open('journey.txt','rb')
thelist = [line.split(';') for line in thefile.readlines()]
thefile.close()

print(thelist)
```

Thanks a looot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there are a few things to comment on here:

1. When you use a `with` statement, you don't have to explicitly close the file. Python will do that for you at the end of the `with` block (line 8).
2. You don't use `todayList` for anything. You create it, add an element and then just discard it. So it's probably useless :)
3. Why are you pickling string object? If you have strings just write them to the file as is.
4. If you pickle data on write you have to unpickle it on read. You shouldn't write pickled data and then just read the file as a plain text file.
5. Use `a` for append when you are just adding items to the file, `w` will overwrite your whole file.

What I would suggest is just writing a plain text file, where every line is one entry.

```
import datetime

def save(data):
    with open('journey.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(data + '\n')

today = datetime.date.today()
page = input('Page Number: ')
feel = input('How do you feel: ')

todaysline = ';'.join([today.strftime('%d, %b %Y'), page, feel])

print('Thanks and Good Bye!')
save(todaysline)

print('let\'s make a list now...')

with open('journey.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip().split(';'))
```

Comment: Thanks Victor. Regarding your code, line 22 does not seem to work out. It seems to me that something is missing no? But is there a way to make my code work by fixing this "must be str, not bytes" error which does not look that complicated at first sight... However i can't find how to fix it. I'm trying to learn what i don't get here :)

Comment: I changed it a little bit, what line is it now? And what version of python are you using?

Comment: Great explanations, fully working code! thanks for your time :)
1) is a good reminder, thanks / 2) :p / 3+4) got it 5) that's what I did not know!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you posted the right code? That error can occur if you miss out the "b" when you open the file

eg.

```
with open('journey.txt', 'w') as thefile:

>>> with open('journey.txt', 'w') as thefile:
...    pickler = pickle.Pickler(thefile)
...    pickler.dump("some string")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

The file should be opened in binary mode

```
>>> with open('journey.txt', 'wb') as thefile:
...    pickler = pickle.Pickler(thefile)
...    pickler.dump("some string")
... 
>>>
```

Comment: yes, it was the right code. I should not have used pickle unless i needed to unpickle.